# Bowtie2 Envronmental Variables

Tags: macos, bioinformatics

I am completely lost with `bowtie2` environment variables. I am using a mac and I downloaded the source file of `bowtie2-2.2.5` and performed `"make"`

The absolute path where this folder is found is

```
/Users/Lab/Documents/CLI_Programs/bowtie2-2.2.5/
```

I want to be able to run the command `bowtie2` without having to be in the folder that contains this. I tried changing my `.bash_profile` with

```
export BT2_HOME=/Users/Kumka/Documents/CLI_Programs/bowtie2-2.2.5/
```

I don't know what this is supposed to look like... Also when I run `./bowtie2` within the folder the final line is

```
(ERR): bowtie2-align exited with value 1
```

Is it even compiled correctly?

Answer (score 0):

```
open ~/.bashrc
```

Add the following path into the .bashrc and save

```
PATH=$PATH:/Users/lab/Documents/CLI_Programs/bowtie2-2.2.5
```

Why don't they just make it so explicit with an example... Geez

Answer (score 0):

I have the same output here

```
(ERR): bowtie2-align exited with value 1
```

This output is caused by insufficient memory

```
Out of memory allocating the ebwt[] array for the Bowtie index.  
Please try again on a computer with more memory.
```